# Convert from Spinning drives to SSD on PERC H700 RAID 1

Tags: centos7, dell, ssd, dell-perc

I have a Dell R510 running a PERC H700 Hardware RAID controller, with 2 2.5" 1TB HDs in a RAID 1 configuation for the OS, and 12 3.5" 2TB HDs in a RAID5 config for a data filesystem.  I have one of the 2.5" drives that failed, so I thought it might be a good time to convert the OS RAID to SSDs to gain some performance and maybe add a bit of storage there.  I got a 2TB SSD drive, but when I plugged it in, the RAID controller would not let me add it to the virtual disk where the OS is, nor even allow me to make it a global spare. Is there a way I can convert the RAID1 partition to SSD without doing a full backup, replace both drives with SSDs, then full restore?

Comment: AFAIK you can't mix SSD's and spinning disks in a single virtual disk, so you can't use your raid controller to migrate with zero downtime from one type of storage to another.

Answer (score 2):

A generic LSI MegaRAID has a variable that enables a feature of mixing HDDs and SSDs and another one that enables a feature of mixing SATA and SAS devices in a single array. PERC, being a rebranded MegaRAID, uses a custom build firmware that has both features permanently disabled. So you can't do this with PERC.

So, you need to really do your backup-and-restore trick, or use spare slots and just do the move. If your OS installation has advanced volume management enabled (e.g. Linux installed on LVM, or Windows with dynamic discs), you may also do this fully online using OS functions: create another virtual disk (use megacli or storcli to do that from an OS), create a physical volume out of it, add it to the group, then move all the data off the old volume; you need to set up booting from the new volume and configure it as a new boot drive in the controller (for the case your system boots off legacy BIOS; this step will involve megacli or storcli). Then you may get rid of old volume and virtual disk or reuse it for something else.